QT: Can I make right-clicking on QTableView always open a new context menu under Linux?
If I test the same QT apps (e.g., Strawberry music player) under Linux (Plasma) and Windows, right-click behaves differently. Under Linux, if I right-click the first item in a list view, it opens the context menu. then, if I right-click the second item, it only closes the context menu for the first item. I have to right-click the second item again to show the context menu for the second item.
Under Windows, the second right-clicking closes the context menu for the first item and opens the context menu for the second item at the same time. That is, every time I right-click the list, a new context menu opens.
Can I get this Windows-like behaviour under Linux when creating a QT app (I am using PySide6, if that matters)? I mean, not by a lot of effort like modifying the QT framework, but by setting some kind of flags or something to the widget (e.g., QTableView) within my code.

Actually, it's a bit different than what you describe, and it's not specific to Qt. The convention on Windows is to open the context menu when the mouse button is released, while on Linux (unless a different configuration is in use) the menu is opened on mouse button press. This is because on Linux you can press the mouse button, keep it pressed while moving the mouse on the desired menu item, and release the button to directly trigger the action. AFAIR, this is also the same on macOS. Now, this makes things difficult, as Qt assumes that behavior and therefore does not send again a »

» mouse press when closing the menu, as the event is automatically ignored. Now, while it's not impossible to achieve that, you'd need to override mouse event handlers for all widgets showing a context menu, and also properly manage the mouse button press received by the menu when clicking outside of it; all this can be quite difficult, especially for Qt widgets that show context menus on their own (eg. QLineEdit): you may think that it wouldn't matter, but then you'd end up with inconsistent behavior of context menus, which can be very annoying to the user. And it would also be »

» inconsistent with the rest of the OS, which can be even more annoying to some (I would be). While I understand your request, I wouldn't worry too much about it: a Linux user is accustomed to that pattern, and changing it would mean a lot of efforts on your part to ensure that it works as expected, while those efforts wouldn't be "enjoyed" so much by users that feel perfectly fine with the established convention and their habits.
